# w3wp Process not found in the list even after restarting IIS

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2019, iis-10

I have a website I want to debug on IIS. Its a pretty straight forward job so I went ahead create a website on IIS and pointed it to a local Solution, So far so good but when I went ahead and tried to attach a debug process to the Website , I was not able to see any w3wp processes , weird thing is that when I restarted IIS , I was indeed able to see the **Default App Pool** w3wp but that`s about it , I am not able to see my websites App Pool.

I have tried all the ways of resolving this. Below are the things I tried:

- Restart IIS (It only shows Default App Pool)
- Refresh the List of debug processes.
- Select specific .NET version instead of Native in Debug List.

Still facing the same issue of not seeing my websites App Pool in the list. Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out why my worker process was not showing , actually my problem was the bindings . What I was doing was setting up the binding to be pointed to the actual server instead of on localhost and also I just had to change the "Name" of the website to be as same the a QC server I have. So Basically, I just changed the below and it started working.

- Changed the name of the App to the actual QC website address.
- Removed the bindings to the QC website and instead pointed to LocalHost.

Answer (score 1):

**General troubleshooting steps for this problem:**

*Tip: To eliminate the possibility of an IDE, you can try to upgrade VS2019 to the latest version.*

1. Open you visual studio 2019 with administrator
2. Enable `Show processes from all users` option in `Attach to Process`.

   [image]
3. As we know website in IIS has a idle time-out, so please access the site in your broswer, make sure you can view the site.
4. Then you can dobuble check the process in the above image.
5. If you still can't find the process, please re-create a new site, and also check whether generate a new application pool. Then you can debug the project in this new site.

Comment: Hi Jason, Unfortunately , I tried all the options above (Creating new website with a new appPool , Browsing the website , and running the VS 2019 as ADMIN) but still no success. Not sure what exactly is happening here. Though I will go ahead and update VS just to be sure.